# Prevent Password being sent over HTTP GET

Tags: asp.net, http, get

I have come across a strange requirement during Security Review where I have to prevent username and password is being sent over HTTP GET in asp.net web forms.

Scenario is like this.

We have  simple asp.net login form with user name, password and Submit button(POST method). During security review, the security tester changes the Form method to GET using some proxy tool(Burp Suite),then the user name and password is sent over as query string.

GET /Login.aspx?_*LASTFOCUS=&*_EVENTTARGET=&_*EVENTARGUMENT=&*_VIEWSTATE=''&_*SCROLLPOSITIONX=0&*_SCROLLPOSITIONY=0&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEWCgKm973fCgKOieLQt9kH6PhK0wq%2FpfP8pXG%2FF&%24txtUser=abc@abc.com&txtPassword=1233&%24btnLogin=Login

As per the security testing team the GET (form method changed to GET using proxy tool)  method should not pass  the user password in query string.(as per my understanding GET will always pass value as query string even if it is password field)

Comment: Please provide some code that makes trouble, we won't think for you.

Comment: Its just a simple asp.net log in form with user name password and submit button. Server side we have btnSumit_Click, validating the username and password against database.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to acheive what you need is to speficy server side to only look at the posted values server side and ignore the query string items, for example by using

```
Request.Form["foo"]
```

Instead of

```
Request["foo"]
```

Or

```
Request.QueryString["foo"]
```

There is no security reason for this, really you just want to be using SSL.